# on Windows Qt Creator where do I enter commands like "cd" "nmake" and "configure"

Tags: windows, qt, console, enter, nmake

I am on windows. I need to make a .exe standalone (static) executable from my completed Qt project.

According to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

to do this I have to do such things as enter this somewhere

```
cd C:\path\to\Qt
configure -static <any other options you need>
```

and

```
nmake clean
qmake -config release
nmake
```

but I have no idea where to do this?! Where do I do this on Windows or on Qt Editor?

Comment: Is nobody even going to attempt to answer this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to start menu, type "cmd" then Enter. It will open a Windows command prompt. That's where commands are supposed to be typed.

Comment: Thanks jpo, I tried that and received an error for "configure", because I didn't have "configure.exe" in the directory. So I thought I must be doing it wrong, nope, I needed to download the Qt Source.

Comment: Sure, it must be easier to compile the sources when you have them ;-)